# Override every Combo getValue Field using common method?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4, overriding

I have combos in extjs application that comob box ID(valueField) HTML encode(because that have special chars)

how can i override every combo getValue method return decode HTML value

Note: i override text-field setValue 
using bellow method

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Base, {
    transformRawValue: function(val) {
        val = Ext.util.Format.htmlDecode(val);
        return this.callParent([val]);
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In 4.x+, overrides have a different syntax.

```
Ext.define("App.overrides.form.ComboBox",{
    override: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    getValue: function () {
        return Ext.util.Format.htmlDecode(this.value);
    }
});
```